# ObjectListView: Binding a list to DataListView

Tags: vb.net, list, data-binding, objectlistview

I'm using the DataListView (from ObjectListView) to bind a custom-object list, but I'm unable to make it work out. Here's my code:

```
Class MediaItem
    Property Title As String
    Property Artist As String
    Property Album As String
End Class

Dim library as New List(Of MediaItem)
dataLV.DataSource = library
```

Now when I add items to the List, I expected the DataListView to automatically populate itself:

```
library.Add(new MediaItem with {....})
```

But this doesn't happen. No items get created in the DataListView control. On the other hand if I populate the List first and then bind it to the DataListView, then it appears fine in the control but then again it doesn't show any changes made to the list.

Can anyone assist on what I'm missing here or whether my concept of using DataListView is incorrect?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of `DataListView` is correct. It's just your data structures that are letting you down.

First, you will need to use an `ObservableCollection` rather than a plain `List`. The `ObservableCollection` will fire events when items are added and removed, and the `DataListView` will add and remove rows accordingly.

Second, if you want to make changes to your `MediaItem` and have those changes automatically appear in the control, then you will have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your `MediaItem` class.

There are literally dozens of places that explain these ideas. Here is a brief description: [List vs ObservableCollection vs INotifyPropertyChanged](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42536/List-vs-ObservableCollection-vs-INotifyPropertyCha)

Comment: Ohk. Thanks. I never knew the good uses of these list types until now.