# DataListView with DataSource of ObservableCollection does not display newly added objects

Tags: vb.net, winforms, observablecollection, objectlistview

1. Created form with a single button and a single DataListView.
2. Added this code to form:

```
    Dim dummies As New ObservableCollection(Of Dummy)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dlvDummies.DataSource = dummies
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        dummies.Add(New Dummy(Now.ToLongTimeString()))
    End Sub

    Class Dummy
        Public Property X As String
        Sub New(x As String)
            Me.X = x
        End Sub
    End Class
```

3. Ran the app, pressed the button. In the debugger, I can visibly see a new entry added to the ObservableCollection and correspondingly to the DataListView .Objects:

[image]

4. Item never appears in the GUI (Yes, the DataListView's sole column is already set up with the aspect name "X" at design time.)

[image]

This is actually a bare bones reproduction of the problem I'm having in a larger app. The answer given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30157854/2112855 implies that this should "just work". Is this a defect, or user error on my part?

Comment: WinForms doesn't have a DataListView, and ObservableCollection is used more in WPF.  WinForms prefers a BindingList.

Comment: Thus the [objectlistview] tag. It's a well-known third party control with its own tag here at SO.

Comment: I'm not sure how this DataListView works, I've never used it. In WinForms, you need an object that can raise `ListChanged` events to notify bound object that the inner list has changed (ObservableCollection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, similar but not the same, so this Control must handle these notifications on its own, a BindingSource won't help here). In any case, your class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, otherwise notifications of changes in the class properties don't reach bound objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing ObservableCollection(Of foo) with BindingList(Of foo) fixed, or rather worked around this.

I think, based on the discussion seen at https://sourceforge.net/p/objectlistview/discussion/812923/thread/ab0d6208/ that the accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30157854/2112855 is faulty and should probably be edited.